# AEM6.1 mobile Apps

Tags: angularjs, phonegap-build, aem

I needed some inputs on mobile apps.
Query: I have an existing web application on AEM(angularJS is not used). I want to transform the same on Mobile app using AEM6.1

While reading through the documentation section of AEM Apps, I found that the mobile App built on AEM 
- works on the terminology and AngularJS framework.
- mobile App has different paths and app structure as compared to AEM web Applications
-since, phonegap has to be used, relative path needs to be different than the same of web application.
I am in a dilemma as If I would be able to convert my existing web app into a mobile App or not. If anyone of you has done some research on this, it would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance!!!

Regards

Comment: Phonegap is not a [webserver or a webbrowser](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#005).

Answer (score 1):

You can very well convert your AEM desktop application to a mobile app(site should be responsive).

AEM makes use of Cordova (PhoneGap) and ContentSync framework to create apps for both android and iOS. More about how to config ContentSync [here](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/developing/mobile/contentsync.html#Overview%20of%20configuration%20types). In simple terms, ContentSync packages your application(/content, /apps, /etc,...) based on defined set of configurations and cordova(phonegap) helps you access native phone capabilities and to create the archive file (apk/ipa). There is more than one way to create an app using AEM.

**1. Using Cordova CLI** :

You [setup](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide/cli/) a cordova project in your filesystem. Then create contentsync configuration for your AEM project. Generate and download the application archive from [here](http://localhost:4502/libs/cq/contentsync/content/console.html). Cordova project you had setup earlier will have the below folder structure.

[image]

Place the contents of archive file inside www folder, modify config.xml according your application and initiate build. Using this method, you will require an Apple system to generate .ipa file since it makes use of xcode and windows makes use of npm node js for the initial dev env setup.

**2. Using OOTB 'Initiate phonegap build' workflow and AEM cloud config**

This is an easy approach and does not require you to setup any cordova project in your system. All you have to do is setup contentsync configuration, add a few properties for the workflow to recognise your project and then trigger the workflow. Follow [this](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/developing/mobile/phonegap_integration.html#Configuring%20PhoneGap%20in%20AEM).

**3. Using Apps console in AEM 6.1**

This also makes use of ContentSync underneath. Apps console makes the app very easy to maintain and configure, it also has inbuilt configurations for push notification, deep linking etc. Go through the info [here](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/mobile-apps/apps/apps-console.html). Refer to the sample geometrixx-outdoors project created in apps console, will help you understand better.

*PS*: Cordova and phonegap are the same. You can think of Cordova as Linux kernel and PhoneGap as linux distribution.